# "At the sight my shirt"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

[walking disaster](https://books.google.jo/books?id=EFmiQFnSNNcC&pg=PT336&dq=%22at%20the%20sight%20my%20shirt%22&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_svW9tdXWAhVoAcAKHZyRBYQQ6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=%22at%20the%20sight%20my%20shirt%22&f=false)

> His stern expression melted into a smile ***at the sight my shirt***, and then he dabbed my face with a towel.

The strong text doesn't make sense unless we put the preposition "of" to be like: at the sight **of** my shirt.

Comment: You are correct. *at the sight **of** {something}*

Comment: Yes. It's an error or a misprint. It's not the kind error that a native English speaker would ever make in speech.

Comment: I though it gives another different meaning with the case of no existed preposition.

Comment: No, the other commenters are correct - it doesn't mean something different without **of**, it's just a mistake.